# Match VirtualHost by X-Forwarded-Host header

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I am using apache 2.4 and would like to create multiple vhosts.
The vhosts should be matched based on the `X-Forwarded-Host` header, instead of the `Host` header.

Unfortunatly I could not find anything in the documentation.
Is this behaviour possible? If yes, how?

To further clarify my problem:
The documentation of the [ServerName directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) states

> If you are using name-based virtual hosts, the ServerName inside a  section specifies what hostname must appear in **the request's Host: header** to match this virtual host.

I am trying to achive the same behaviour, but based on `X-Forwarded-Host`

Comment: could you elaborate on your use-case?

Comment: @criztovyl: the server is behind a cloud based reverse proxy, handling caching,  tls offloading and other things. Since it is an L7 appliance it makes a new http request. The host is always set to the host the server as known to the reverse proxy. the original host name is set as x-forwarded-host.

Comment: Hace you checked whether the reverse proxy allows you to set the outgoing host header?

Comment: 1975274943oting to close. This is not showing no best practices, but seems to show total lack of  basic knowledge and effort to use a search engine. I am NOT an apache person, but out of interest I typed "apache x-forwarded-host" into google and... found https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html Using google with "apache mod_proxy x-forwarded-host" points me to https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf59/using-apache-with-virtual-hosts-and-mod_proxy-792499654.html among other things. This site is not meant to be a first utility, one has to show effort first - this totally seems to lack.

Comment: @TomTom what you found is for proxy, the question is about virtual hosts.

Comment: @criztovyl: yes, but it is not supported. As I take from Mozilla ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host ) and personal experience, X-Forwarded-*, or the Forwared header is the way to go from a best practice perspective.

Comment: @TomTom: As stated in the original question I am not trying to proxy requests, but trying to select the vhost based on the header

Comment: Simply configure the reverse proxy correctly so that it preserves the original Host header (or remove the setting where you override the default behavior and override the Host) and avoid the whole issue completely.

Comment: @HBruijn this specific reverse proxy does not seem to support that.

Comment: @stena could you assign more IP addresses to your apache machine and set up the virtual hosts based on that?

Comment: @criztovyl: unfortunatly the ip addresses are indeterministic in my environment

Comment: what cloud platform are you on, what reverse proxy are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussions in the comment, I assume it seems to be impossible to do out of the box.

The easiest workaround seems to enforcing Host header preservation outside the webserver.

In case it is impossible to change at the L7 appliance setting the Host header, an option would be to add another reverse proxy, with the sole purpose, writing the XFH header to the Host header. This could be actually another apache2 httpd (recycling @Tomtom's comment here), but there are probably solutions with a smaller footprint for this purpose.

Another option to investigate would be to write a dedicated mod for Apache, while I am not sure if it is a good idea to swap the detected server name since it seems to be tied very deeply in the source.

What definitly did not work was trying to override the host header using apache config directives using `RequestHeader set Host ...`.
It changed the header, but did not have effect on vhost selection.